# What's the meaning of Std and WGL on Typefaces?

Tags: typefaces, opentype

Taking for example the [Rockwell](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/rockwell) OTF typeface. There are three "classes" inside of it:

- Rockwell
- Rockwell Std
- Rockwell WGL

Are those particular to this typeface, or they mean something in general when we are talking about typefaces? Checking the glyphs I didn't spot any difference between `Rockwell` and `Rockwell WGL Regular`, the only difference is between `Rockwell Std` and the others, as the first one has less glyphs.

Comment: More information in http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29431/30216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Std means "standard" and can have different meanings depending on the foundry. The difference between [Rockwell](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/rockwell/rockwell/) and [Rockwell Std](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/rockwell/std-roman/) appears to be a difference in symbols included as well as minor differences in letter spacing and line height.

WGL fonts only support [Windows Glyph List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Glyph_List_4) characters.

---

For information about other font name abbreviations, I find [this list](http://blog.extensis.com/fonts/abbreviations-font-names.php) to be helpful.

Comment: So, using a WGL typeface is preferred over a non-WGL one? There's no need to install both, `TypefaceXYZ` and `TypefaceXYZ WGL`?

Comment: It depends on your usage I suppose but WGL and regular seem the same to me. I can't think of many reasons why you'd need both installed